# How to find the no of people following a hashtag - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-taggit

I have used [Django-Taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in the posts to add tagging in my project.
My post model schema is like this :

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
      on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='feedposts')
    publish =models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ***
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

In order to make user follow the hashtags. I have added this field in the User Model Schema which looks like this.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ****
    following_tags = TaggableManager()
```

Then if the user follows the particular tag, I add that particular tag in the listed field.

Now we can get the feed according to the hashtags user is following. But now I want to find out the total number of people following a particular hashtag and this is something I am not able to do.
Also, Please tell me if there is any other implementation from which I can achieve this feature using django-taggit since it is easy without using it by just making a simple table of FollowedHashtags like below

```
class FollowedHashtags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique = True)
    user = models.ManyTOManyField(User)
```

We can get the no of people following the Hashtags:

```
hashtag = FollowedHashtags.objects.get(id=1)
nooffollowers = hashtag.user.count()
```

I have tried some filtering queries but no success yet. So if know any other implementation or way or you could suggest me the right way. I would be highly thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do for you

```
 FollowedHashtags.objects.filter(id=1).values('user').count()
```